# Painting gives unusual results, black portions of window

Tags: c++, winapi, paint

I'm creating a win32 application in C++ and trying (unsuccessfully) to keep things somewhat object-orientated while still respecting the winapi message loop etc.

The problem I'm having is that my window seems to be drawing inconsistently and/or in a weird way that I have not encountered before.  Eg:

[image: Window Image]

This occurs when the window is resized.  If I minimize the window and open it again, everything is black, apart from the buttons.  Also, when moving my mouse from outside the window into the window, whatever my cursor was before getting inside the window is retained.  For example, if there is a textbox behind the window, and I move my cursor from the textbox and into this window, the cursor remains the caret cursor.

I'm using this code to handle messages inside my `WindowMain` class:

```
std::map<HWND, WindowMain*> WindowMain::HWNDMap;
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowMain::WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (HWNDMap.find(hWnd) == HWNDMap.end()) { return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam); }
    return HWNDMap[hWnd]->InstWndProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowMain::InstWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (msg) {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        DeleteObject(_hFont);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The `WindowMain::WndProc` function is a static member of `WindowMain`.  I use a `std::map` to map `HWND` to `WindowMain*` so that I can pass messages from the static method to the relevant `WindowMain::InstWndProc`.  I feel like the problem might be here but I can't spot it.

In case it's relevant, this is the code I'm using to create the window:

```
WindowMain::WindowMain(HINSTANCE hInst) {
    _isReady = false;

    WNDCLASS wc;
    memset(&wc, 0, sizeof(wc));
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.lpszClassName = ClassName.c_str();
    wc.hInstance = hInst;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(0);

    if (!RegisterClass(&wc)) { return; }

    _hWnd = CreateWindow(ClassName.c_str(), "AlchemyAC", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 400, 300, NULL, NULL, hInst, NULL);
    if (!_hWnd) { return; }

    _hBtnStart = CreateWindow("BUTTON", "Start", WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 10, 10, 100, 24, _hWnd, NULL, hInst, NULL);
    _hBtnStop = CreateWindow("BUTTON", "Stop", WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 10, 39, 100, 24, _hWnd, NULL, hInst, NULL);
    if (!_hBtnStart || !_hBtnStop) { return; }

    GetObject(GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT), sizeof(LOGFONT), &_lf);
    _hFont = CreateFont(_lf.lfHeight, _lf.lfWidth,
        _lf.lfEscapement, _lf.lfOrientation, _lf.lfWeight,
        _lf.lfItalic, _lf.lfUnderline, _lf.lfStrikeOut, _lf.lfCharSet,
        _lf.lfOutPrecision, _lf.lfClipPrecision, _lf.lfQuality,
        _lf.lfPitchAndFamily, _lf.lfFaceName);

    SendMessage(_hBtnStart, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)_hFont, true);
    SendMessage(_hBtnStop, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)_hFont, true);

    EnableWindow(_hBtnStop, false);

    HWNDMap[_hWnd] = this;
    _isReady = true;
}
```

My question is, why is this strange painting issue occurring?  I'm mainly interested in the odd thing that is happening with the cursor.

EDIT: I *am* using a while loop to translate and dispatch messages.

Comment: You didn't set WNDCLASS.hbrBackground and you don't handle WM_ERASEBKGND either.  So you are seeing the back of your monitor.  Hehe.

Comment: I can see the comedic value in that!  I've changed `hbrBackground` and it has fixed one problem, thanks very much.  Do you have any idea why this issue with the cursor is occurring?  It's difficult to demonstrate but I think I explained it well enough above.

Comment: The window class also includes a field specifying which cursor you want by default IIRC, and memsetting it to zero might mean "whatever it was before the mouse entered this window". That's only an educated guess, though - it's a long time since I used WIN32.

Comment: I tried not `memset`ting the WNDCLASS, that didn't work, and I also tried `LoadCursor` with `IDC_ARROW` for the `hCursor` property and that also didn't work.  Your idea sounds right to me though so I'll check further.

Comment: A stab in the dark - it's usually `???.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL,
IDC_ARR0W);`. The first argument is an instance handle, but not the instance to your program - `IDC_ARROW` is a shared resource, not a resource in your program - therefore `NULL`. Probably not your problem but it's all I can think of ATM.

Comment: @HansPassant - you caught the first uninitialized field - do you want this?

Comment: @Steve314 - I already voted to close as "typo", it is all yours.